# how can I change the implementation of FlashBag messages in Symfony2

Tags: session, symfony, message

I know there are two implementations available for flashBag messages: the autoexpire and the normal one. Both implement the same interface.
How can I configure my session to use the non-expire implementation.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it's better to use normal session instead of flashBag messages for non-expire implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify it in your `parameters.yml` as such:

```
parameters:
    # your parameters
    session.flashbag.class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\AutoExpireFlashBag
```

But as advised in the above comment it's there only for legacy reasons and is for example not ESI-compliant.

Comment: Thanks all for the response. Just one question: Can I change the implementation dynamically?

Comment: You can do that via `CompilerPass`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html